# Fontawesome Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, font-awesome

Normalmente no suelo trabajar con Wordpress. Pero desarrolle hace tiempo esta web y me encuentro el problema que al añadir el icono de WhatsApp en el header, no me lo lee. Entiendo que estara desactualizado o no lee bien el código. Pero la verdad que desde wordpress no se como solucionar que me lo lea.

El link de la web es este: https://nashi.es/

No pongo nada más ya que no se que es lo que puedo mostrar para que me ayudeis. Gracias

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons/whatsapp
en fontawesome 5 las brands estan agrupadas en la clase fab, cambiale a `<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>`

Comment: @aloMalbarez tiene la versión 3.2 de FA, en la [lista de iconos de esa versión](https://fontawesome.com/v3.2.1/icons/) no aparece WhatssApp.

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene ambas versiones, o le cambia el font-weight a ese icono o cambia la clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El icono de WhatssApp fue agregado a partir de la versión `4.2` de FontAwesome, pero tú estás usando la version `3.2`, por lo tanto no te funcionará.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quizá sea el momento de actualizar a la última versión que ya va por la versión `5`.

### Versión 5.12

Aquí funciona:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-mmgLkCYLUQbXn0B1SRqzHar6dCnv9oZFPEC1g1cwlkk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<i class="fab fa-whatsapp">ico-Sí</i>
```

### Versión 3.2 (la tuya actual)

Aquí no funciona:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha256-bNPGnNxsIr8mZ4p5VH3uYQorlucOUehl8ml0jm1LZ2I=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<i class="fab fa-whatsapp">ico-NO</i>
```

Comment: Solo tengo que cambiar la versión de fontawesome? Es decir desde header?

Comment: @Miguel sí, Si pones esto: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-mmgLkCYLUQbXn0B1SRqzHar6dCnv9oZFPEC1g1cwlkk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />` te funcionará, y además tomará el archivo desde el CDN de FA directamente, descargando así a tu servidor de la responsabilidad de guardar el archivo. No olvides de quitar la carga del FA antiguo.

Comment: El problema que los iconos me los saca no se muy bien de donde, y por mucho que actualice eso no me funciona. Es decir, donde pongo eso puedo elegir entre iconos diferentes, no se como hacer

Comment: Vale ya lo tengo listo, estaba cargando dos librerias de FontAwesome, gracias!